# How to disable webcam via js?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a feature that should take a photo and turn off the webcam, but it doesn't turn off.

**I've tried:**

```
localStream.getTracks()[0].stop();
localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
localStream.stop();
```

**There is my code:**

```
click: function() {
    context.drawImage(video,0,0,w,
    var blob = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    preview.attr('src', blob);
    inputBin.val(blob);
    if (localStream!== undefined){
        video.pause();
        video.src = "";
        localStream.getTracks()[0].stop();
    }
    select.val(null);
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
```

I expect that webcam turned off.

Comment: P.S. I used navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Comment: var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
var video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.srcObject = mediaStream;
            video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                video.play();
            };

Comment: This is a commercial code, and therefore I can’t show the whole function and provide a minimum to solve the problem.

Comment: You don't need to show anything from your real code. You have to create an [MCVE], that is something that does reproduce the issue you are facing with nothing more than what needs to be there to reproduce the issue. [Here is a base for you](https://jsfiddle.net/w1kez3hm/) if you wish, although this base works... all you have to do is to include just what is necessary to make it fail. We don't want to read your code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. Code was not mine and I didn't see that localStream is not defined..

Comment: Since there is very little chance that this Q/A helps anyone in the future (not that nobody will have the same issue, we all already had it, several times, but rather that they won't be able to find it) you might want to simply delete it. Note that we have a close reason just for that, and that I have voted in this direction.